# Merge a specific file from different branch/directory

Tags: git

I have two GIT branches:
A with Pluto/test.txt
B with Pippo/test.txt

I want to merge only the file (test.txt) in the branch B into A.

I tried to use:

```
git checkout A
git checkout B Pippo/test.txt
```

but this creates a folder with the file in it like:
A with Pluto/test.txt and Pippo/test.txt.
However I would like to get a merge of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git merge-file`. It merges two files in three-way merge.

```
git merge-file <current-file> <base-file> <other-file>
```

In your case, `current-file` is A's `Pluto/test.txt`, `other-file` is B's `Pippo/test.txt`. As for `base-file`, you could find out which commit of A introduced `Pluto/test.txt` for the first time, by `git log A --reverse -- Pluto/test.txt`. The first commit in the output is what we want and suppose it's `abc123`.

Checkout the branch A, so that we have `current-file`.

```
git checkout A
```

Retrieve `base-file`.

```
git cat-file -p abc123:Pluto/test.txt > base.txt
```

Retrieve `other-file`.

```
git cat-file -p B:Pippo/test.txt > other.txt
```

Run the three-way file merge.

```
git merge-file Pluto/test.txt base.txt other.txt
```

Open `Pluto/test.txt`. If there are any conflicts, solve them. Save and exit. Add and commit the changes.

```
git add Pluto/test.txt
git commit
```

Clean `base.txt` and `other.txt`.

```
rm base.txt other.txt
```

Comment: Another plumbing command I didn't play with enough yet :-) Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

git won't merge files which have a different path.

A file merge *could* occur if both files were on the same exact path, but different on your branches.

However, even if you had, let's say, `Pluto/test.txt` in each branch, merging B into A would not necessarily result in a merge. It would **only** if they both differed from their [merge base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) in the same places (chunks of code).

Maybe consider doing a manual merge with any merge tool, then commiting these changes on the branch you need?